# проблема с вытаскиванием рандомных цифр и букв с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, token, re

Всем здравствуйте есть у меня вот такой код:

```
test = 'urity_login" value="9840405db2" /><inpu'
m = re.search(r'value=(".+?")', test)
print(m.group(0))
```

и в `m.group(0)` он мне возвращает `value="9840405db2"` как сделать чтобы он возвращал только цифры и буквы которые содержаться в скобках: вместо `value="9840405db2"` должно быть`9840405db2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда нужно указывать номер группы, а не `0`, если вы хотите получить то, что в конкретной группе в скобках:

```
print(m.group(1))
```

Вывод:

```
"9840405db2"
```

Кавычки у вас тоже внутри скобок, если что.